# Alternate to global variable in Python

Tags: python, recursion, global

I am implementing a recursive function in which I need to remember a global value. I will decrement this value in every recursive call and want it to reflect in other recursive calls also.

Here's a way I've done it.

First way:

```
global a
a = 3
def foo():
    global a
    if a == 1:
        print 1
        return None
    print a
    a -= 1    # This new 'a' should be available in the next call to foo()
    foo()
```

The output:

```
3
2
1
```

But I want to use another way because my professor says global variables are dangerous and one should avoid using them.

Also I am not simply passing the variable 'a' as argument because 'a' in my actual code is just to keep track of some numbers, that is to track the numbering of nodes I am visiting first to last. So, I don't want to make my program complex by introducing 'a' as argument in every call.

Please suggest me whatever is the best programming practice to solve the above problem.

Comment: Passing a variable does not add complexity... it makes sure you're only changing a variable when you intend to, where you intend to.

Comment: Using a parameter (which is a local variable) is faster than looking up a global, and is far less complex in the long run than dealing with global variables.

Comment: I meant complexity not in terms of run time but in terms of program readability. Wouldn't it make the code look more cumbersome?

Comment: Considering the version with parameters uses 2-3 fewer lines than the version with globals... No.

Comment: I've been told to use DRY principle. So, basically what I want to know is that, given a code that does DFS, I want to change it so that it prints the number of nodes it visits in order. Now, I am not sure whether I should use 'a' as parameter to keep track of number of nodes or should I use global variable.

Comment: This might have been easier if you posted your 'actual code' from the beginning. You are asking us questions about code that you did not post. Answering in a vacuum: don't use global variables.

Comment: Sorry! I'll keep that in mind on my next question. Thank you everyone for helping me out. I am new here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this :
Use a parameter instead of a global variable.
Example code

```
a = 3


def foo(param):
        if param == 1:
            print 1
            return None
        print param
        foo(param - 1)

foo(a)
```

Comment: This is the correct answer, and the functional method I think is more Pythonic than the OO class-based method above.

Answer (score 7):

Don't use a global; just make `a` a parameter to the function:

```
def foo(a):
    print a
    if a == 1:
        return None
    foo(a-1)

foo(3)
```